# Debian can't communicate with network printer

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, debian, printing, printer

We have working Konica Minolta Bizhub C224e connected to Wi-Fi.

Windows computers don't have problems with it, so I assume that it's configured properly.

On my Debian Wheezy I can see this printer as "KONICA_MINOLTA_C364Series", in model field it says "KONICA MINOLTA C554Series OpenOffice PPD". I have CUPS 1.5.3 installed.

When I commit printing, I see "processing" status and then "Not connected?" Debian suggestion.

Please tell me how to debug it, I can provide all further information.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same printer, which is working most of the time with linux (Debian Wheezy and Jessie) clients. The Konica Minolta website offers 2 PPD files for download, and I am using the other one (not the OpenOffice, but the UX version). This might solve your problem. Another cause could be the way the printer is configured: I use `lpd://<ip-address>/Print`
But I have read somewhere that a `socket://` -connection might solve my remaining issues with this printer (being not able to print some documents while throwing a PDF-error)

Comment: Thanks. Now I can't acces this machine, so if this work for someone, please let me know.

Comment: What do you mean? It 'works for me' - what would you like to see confirmed?

Comment: I mean that if someone confirmed that Your answer help, I will accept it, because I can't check it on my own ;)